Is it just me or does YouTube's Data API not return fields shown in its documentation
I'm using the YouTube Data API endpoint to fetch a list of videos on my channel
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
The documentation itself says it returns 2 fields for pagination:

nextPageToken
prevPageToken

Every request I make, no matter how many pages I go down, it only returns nextPageToken, I never receive prevPageToken.
Even in the API Explorer, same results.
The request URL that's being built looks like this:
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
(There's no pageToken in this case because it would be getting the first page of results)
Am I just doing something silly? Or is the documentation just wrong.
I thought maybe it returns the prevPageToken only when you're 2 pages or so deep, but nope, doesn't change anything.

As far as I know people do not really care about prevPageToken, so I would absolutely not be surprised that the documentation is wrong.

How would I approach pagination then if I don't want to be saving the values to a database? Because if I go too many pages down, you no longer have the ability to get back to earlier pages.

You can at least save next page tokens which then are equivalent to previous page tokens. I do not really see the point of not storing the results but the page tokens, especially as they are not permanent as I understand their Protobuf structure.
